# windows phone 7 equilvalent of android's progress dialog?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In android there is a progress dialog class??

> ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
>                           "Loading. Please wait...", true);

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610068/how-should-i-indicate-progress-in-a-windows-phone-7-app-if-im-not-going-to-show/9632692#9632692

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ProgressIndicator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.progressindicator%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

```
<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
    <shell:ProgressIndicator IsIndeterminate="True" IsVisible="True" Text="Click me..." />
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is ProgressBar control comes with SDK, also PerformanceProgressBar in Silverlight Toolkit exists (a little bit better).
In WP7.1 you have an access to SystemTray. It has an option to show that some actions happen (indeterminate or in percents) with additional message if you want